# SQL Server Query - how transpose line by line and stack them up?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to transform the following table:

```
ID      Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4
112233  1     2     3     4
112233  5     6     7     8
112233  9     10    11    12
```

into something like the following

```
ID      VarName      Value
112233     Var1      1
112233     Var1      2
112233     Var1      3
112233     Var1      4
112233     Var2      5
112233     Var2      6
112233     Var2      7
112233     Var2      8
112233     Var3      9
112233     Var3      10
112233     Var3      11
112233     Var3      12
```

Is there an simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unpivot:

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13fbc7cab4d6ab891b682d987d823438)

```
select id,varname, value from tablename
Unpivot
(
  value for varname in (var1, var2, var3,var4)

) as UnPvt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` :

```
select id, VarName, value
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('Var1', var1), ('Var2', var2), ('Var3', var3)
     ) tt (VarName, value)
order by VarName;
```